# Работа с набором JQuery

Tags: jquery

Написал скроллер. Хочу к кликнутому пункту сделать допвыборку элемента и применить к нему стили. Подскажите правильный синтаксис выборки. Интересует вот эта строка `$(this).$("menu.main-mnu > ul > li").addClass("active");`

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function() {
  var _href = $(this).attr("href");
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(_href).offset().top + "px"
  }, 2000);
  $("menu.main-mnu > ul > li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).$("menu.main-mnu > ul > li").addClass("active");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest("menu.main-mnu > ul > li").addClass("active");
```

Comment: спасибо, помогли